# how to use a cuda class header file in both cpp and cuda modules

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to create Color object in my device. Here's a simplified version of what I have:

In ***Color.hpp***:

```
class Color { 
public:
    Color(){}
    float r, g, b;
    // other functions
}
```

In ***test.cu***:

```
__global__ void runCuda(){
    Color c = Color();
}

int main() {
   runCuda<<<1,1>>>()
}
```

This gives me an error saying that

> calling a **host** function from a **global** function is not allowed

So this is fine. I simply need to add __host__ and __device__ in front of Color(){} function.

But then i get the following error:

> **host** does not name a type

So from what I understand, this is happening because I am not compiling it with nvcc. The problem is I am using CMake to build my project. I am not too sure how it does it but it seems like it is compiling .cpp files with the c++ compiler and .cu with nvcc compiler.

But in my device, I want to create Color object. Is there a way to fix this either in my CMakefiles or in my code? Or do i need to create a cuda version for all my existing classes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define CUDA_HOSTDEV __host__ __device__
#else
#define CUDA_HOSTDEV
#endif

class Color { 
public:
    CUDA_HOSTDEV Color(){}
    float r, g, b;
    // other functions
};
```

When your hpp file is included in a .cu file, the `__CUDACC__` [macro](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-identification-macro) will be defined.  When it is included in a .cpp file (which nvcc hands off to the host compiler) the macro will not be defined.

Comment: i simply copied what you had, and c++ compiler worked like expected but nvcc compiler gave me the same error.

Comment: I think so. (The constructor is a function in class Color.)  Try it.

Comment: hmm for constructors, it seems to work fine but for some functions, i get errors saying "Unresolved extern function function_name"

Comment: I tried it for a simple getter function.  It seemed to work fine for me.  You might need to provide an example.  I would suggest asking a new question.  You might simply be getting tripped up over class usage rather than anything specific to `__host__` `__device__` usage.

Comment: If I attempt to define Color() in a .cpp file I get a build error, thoughts on what to do if we really want to implement a function in a .cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like the following.

```
#ifndef __host__
#define __host__
#endif

#ifndef __device__
#define __device__
#endif
```

With this approach, you won't need to modify your code. I'm not sure if this is kosher, but it seems to work with my projects. You should probably include these defines *after* you include the CUDA headers.